# sum of exterior angles of a closed broken line in space

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am looking for a simple proof of the following fact:
The sum of exterior angles of any closed broken line in space is at least $2 \pi$. I believe it equals $2 \pi$ if and only if the closed broken line equals a polygon.

Comment: whats the difference between a closed broken line and a polygon?

Comment: a closed broken line need not be planar

Comment: A useful keyword: you are asking about a lower bound to the [total curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature) of a broken line. It seems like at least some articles on this subject call such a line a polygon even if it is non-planar, so don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [*Curves of Finite Total Curvature*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606007v2) by J. Sullivan:

> **Lemma 2.1.** (See[[Mil50](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969467), Lemma 1.1] and [[Bor47](http://fbc.pionier.net.pl/id/oai%3arcin.org.pl:20023)].)
>   Suppose $P$ is a polygon in $\mathbb E^d$. If $P'$ is obtained from $P$ by deleting one vertex $v_n$ then $\operatorname{TC}(P')\leq\operatorname{TC}(P)$. We have equality here if $v_{n-1}v_nv_{n+1}$ are collinear in that order, or if $v_{n-2}v_{n-1}v_nv_{n+1}v_{n+2}$ lie convexly in some two-plane, but never otherwise.

This total curvature $\operatorname{TC}$ is the sum of exterior angles you are asking about. You could reduce every closed broken line to a triangle by successive removal of vertices. Since the total curvature of a triangle is always $2\pi$, this gives the lower bound you assumed.

And with the other condition, you can argue that in the case of equality the last vertex you deleted must have been in the same plane as the triangle, and subsequently every vertex deleted before that, and hence the whole curve must have been a planar and convex polygon.